# How can I call methods on Reactjs components in the browser console or from an outside script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a leaflet map component, here is an example on plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/LkghwOcby49XESdGb782?p=preview

here is the code

leaflet.jsx

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
/*jshint indent: 2, node: true, nomen: true, browser: true*/
/*global React */

'use strict';
module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      map: {}
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    this.setState({map: map});
  },
  modifyMap: function (method, options) {
    this.setState({
      map : this.state.map[method](options.latLong, options.zoom, options.zoom_options)
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      /* jshint ignore:start */
      <div id="map"></div>
      /* jshint ignore:end */
    );
  }
});
```

map.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Leafy</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div class="container">
      <div id="leaflet"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.11.0/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="leaflet.jsx"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to try and call the modifyMap method directly from the browser console or from any script on the page. I have tried to use statics but I am unable to find the Object which contains the modifyMap method. Is there an easy way to find this method or is there a better way of doing this with Reactjs? I also know that this is possible if the React class was created on this page instead of using module.exports in a separate file, I am hoping there is another way! Please help!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to call methods on the component *instance*, you need to make it available at some point during the component's lifecycle. For example, if you have only one such map on the page, you could do something like this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  // ...
  this.setState({map: map});
  window.map = this;
}
```

Now, you can access the component from the global `map` variable:

[image: Screencast]

Standard disclaimer: while this can be useful from time to time, especially when debugging, if you find yourself doing this very often, you should revisit your use of React—namely, you should generally pass properties into components, which the component would then use to update itself.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I should've thought of that

Comment: that's horrible. Talk about side effects

Comment: omg. you know people are ignoring the disclaiming and using this in prod.

Comment: what side effect could this have? for people like me who is new to react and trying to do this in prod

Comment: i think for security reason, since anyone could call and update the value for your map

Answer (score 8):

call component methods externally:

```
var app= React.renderComponent( <app/>, document.getElementById('app') );
app.modifyMap(arg1, arg2) //or anything else
```

or from another component:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    this.refs.myApp.modifyMap(arg1, arg2) // Etc.
},
render: function(){
    return <div>
        <App ref='myApp'/>
    </div>
}
```

**but** your 'modifyMap' method is anti thinking in react!
use componentDidMount to affect map according to this.props only, and change them in Map parrent component. your Map instance should be something like

```
<Map center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} [...] />
```

Comment: does not work within <script>app.modifyMap(...)</script> I am using <script type="text/babel"> for my component and not <script type="text/jsx">